# What is the Stata equivalent of R functions unique and aggregate?

Tags: r, stata

I am trying to convert some R files into Stata files.

These are the code in R (`x2016_precinct_president` is the data file)

```
votesCounty <- aggregate(X2016_precinct_president$votes, by=list(
                        X2016_precinct_president$county_fips,
                        X2016_precinct_president$candidate_fec), FUN=sum)
counties <- (unique(votesCounty$Group.1))
```

I tried to do the following in Stata

```
egen votes_sum = sum(votes), by (county_fips candidate_fec)
keep votes_sum county_fips candidate_fec 
duplicates drop county_fips, force
```

But the problem is that the numbers of observations left after these operations are different across Stata and R. Does anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: Please rephrase this in terms of an explicit reproducible example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I think there might be better ways to do it with either `R` and `Stata`, if you explain what you want to achieve with a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

collapse (sum) votes, by(county_fips candidate_fec)
duplicates drop

Collapse command in stata aggregates the data by the different levels you specify. You can choose whether you want the sum/mean/etc of the variable in interest as it is aggregated.

You use egen sum and bysort if you want access to a aggregate group information by unit of observation so that you can use it for a calculation by each of the detailed units of observation. For eg: If you want to calculate what percent of college educated people are in each county and have county wide information, you would use bysort to group by county and calculate total for counties and have that total as a separate variable. Then, you can calculate percentage of college educated people in each county.

Aggregation is when you just want average number/total number of college educated people by county. In that case, you would just do collapse.